# Individual column searching (select inputs) renderDatatable() in Shiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, datatables, shiny

I am trying to have Individual Column Searching (Select Inputs) using Datatables in a Shiny application

Following this link, http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html I tried to add the requisite javascript code to the R code in my shiny application's server.R file.

As far as I know, by default renderDataTable has individual search boxes which I turned off using `searching = FALSE` and then passed the js function at the above mentioned link  as callback in my renderDataTable code.

```
callback = "initComplete: function (oTable) {
  var api = this.api();
  api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
    var column = api.column( i );
    var select = $('<select><option value=\"\"></option></select>')
    .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
    .on( 'change', function () {
      var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
        $(this).val()
      );
      column
      .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
      .draw();
    } );
    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
      select.append( '<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>' )
    } );
  } );
}"
```

No Changes are reflected in the Shiny Application when I run the application with the above code. I had errors due to the various quotes inside the `I()` block which I solved(or did not) by adding escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others are looking also for this:

Here you'll find examples on using filters on specific columns:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html

server.R

In this case, only my column 1 has a searching box in the bottom.

```
   output$mytable <- renderDataTable(df, options = list(
                        columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(2,3, 4,5,6,7) - 1, searchable = FALSE)),
                        pageLength = 10

                ))
```